# magicsuggest: make drop-box wider than input box

Tags: jquery, magicsuggest

I am using magicsuggest to create a dropbox with options, similar to Scrabblebox http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/examples.html

I'd like for the drop-down box of options to be wider than the input box that shows the selected options. However, the width is set by Macigsuggest based on the width of the input box. It is inline css, so I cannot overwrite it with a CSS class.

I tried making jquery that sets the width, but the drop-down box does not exist until the user starts typing and it then drops down.

Comment: Have you tried to override `.ms-res-ctn` ?

Comment: What do you mean by override? I've tried adding css style to the class, but it does not override the inline css.

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/bubbliscious/wzruL1wL/1/